# GPS + GPRS in Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, gps, modules, gsm

I'm a newbie on what regards to electronic projects, but **I will like to set up a GPS tracker to transmit coordinates over a GPRS internet connection (3G or so).**

I found some Add-Ons that may work but I'm not sure if it is possible to add both. The products are:

- GPS -> https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on-v2-0.html
- GSM/GPRS -> https://www.itead.cc/development-platform/raspi/add-on/raspberry-pi-sim900-gsm-gprs-add-on-v1-0.html OR https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-sim800-gsm-gprs-add-on-v2-0.html

**Will these products work simultaneously with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPS module you've linked has a strange connector on the top. It's very unlikely that you can put the GSM/GPRS module on it, so I will say:

**NO, they won't work together.**

I would go with this GPS and a USB modem. I have tested this one with a raspberry : `Huawei E3372`, but it seems at little bit overpriced.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! And if I buy the GSM/GPRS module and buy a component like this [link](https://www.amazon.com/GlobalSat-BU-353-S4-USB-Receiver-Black/dp/B008200LHW/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1510577628&sr=1-1&keywords=BU-353) to get the GPS coordinates? It is possible?

Comment: Most USB GPS are simply serial GPS behind a serial-to-usb bridge, so they generally work fine under Linux.
I really like and use the raspberry pi platform, but whenever I can choose a peripheral that will work on a standard PC, I buy this one over the raspberry pi specific. So I can only recommend going the USB way.

Comment: Thank you! So I will buy the SIM800 Add-On (GSM/GPRS) and the BU-353-S4 (GPS)

Comment: What about this product? [link](https://www.makerfabs.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=135)
It has both funcionalities that I need. It is compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3?